# How to have two or more textviews autofit the available space and all have the same textsize?

Tags: android, textview, autosize

I'm trying to fit 3 textviews along with other widgets horizontally, I can do that be have the textsize for all of them as small as possible however on bigger screens it doesn't look nice.
[image]

is there a possible way to use autosizing feature in TextView for each TextView and still have the same textsize in all?

Comment: you can use @dimens for textsizes. In this way android will display the specific text size according to the screen resolution.

Comment: @Umair the content is not always the same so having specific text sizes does not help for different screen sizes.

Comment: as i understood you need each TextView be auto size but all TextViews have same text size ,right?

Comment: @Saeid yes so in other words they should have the minimum textsize required for all the textviews

Comment: @atabouraya have yo look here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html ?